# create stock index page for new directory php

Tags: php

Ok everyone, I've done something similar to this last year but I've forgotten how I did it. What I am trying to do is make a new directory via the (organic ie. custom made) admin panel and in that directory automatically put a stock index page on it that dynamically populates with content.

```
      if (!is_dir('../../' . $parent . '/' . $name . '')) {
        mkdir('../../' . $parent . '/' . $name . '', 0777, true);
      }
```

So this is how I am making the directory, but I'm not sure how to insert this "stock" index page. Any hints? I'm sure it's been done before by others but I can't find any resources on it, perhaps im asking google and SO magic search bars the wrong question.

Comment: What's the point of ` . '' ` ?

Comment: I would create a default stock PHP page and save it someplace in your server.  Once the directory is created, copy the stock `index.php` to the created directory.

Comment: @MarkBaker organization mostly.

Comment: @Jason oh yeah, i suppose that could work, ill try it out, if you want to put it in an answer so i can accept it i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a default stock `index.php` file somewhere in the server.  For example,

```
$SERVER_ROOT/app/defaults/index.php
```

When the directory is created via the `mkdir` function, copy that `index.php` to the new directory.

If the default `index.php` includes images, graphics or other dependences, don't forget to update the references as well, or they won't show.  This will also prevent the creation of duplicate resources.